# Using semi-transparent palettes in bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I would like to create a color palette in [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) that has varying alpha values, so some colors are semi-transparent.

I tried to pass some RGBA value as hex (`#33eedd777`) or CSS colors (`rgba(129, 23, 43, 90)`) as a palette but bokeh raised a `ValueError`.

Here is a code example:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from bokeh.util.hex import hexbin

n = 50000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = np.random.standard_normal(n)

bins = hexbin(x, y, 0.1)

p = figure(tools="wheel_zoom,reset", match_aspect=True, background_fill_color='#440154')
p.grid.visible = False

cm = ['#08459400', '#f7fbffff']
cm = ['rgba(80, 80, 80, 10)', 'rgba(8, 8, 8, 255)', ]

p.hex_tile(q="q", r="r", size=0.1, line_color=None, source=bins,
           fill_color=linear_cmap('counts', cm, 0, max(bins.counts)))
show(p)
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code you have been trying.

Comment: Sure, I've just done that.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0`, this appears to be a bug. The `Seq(Color)` property of `LinearColorMap` is supposed to accept lists of RGBA tuples, e.g. `[(100, 80, 200, 0.2), ...]` and it does accept them without a validation error, but does not generate correct output. That is the answer, there is no other information to add, or workarounds to give at this time (CSS color strings cannot be used, and hex color codes cannot have an alpha).

I would encourage you to file a bug report on GitHub with this information so that it may be fixed for all users:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues